# Postgres bytea error when binding null to prepared statements

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am working with a Java application which uses JPA and a Postgres database, and I am trying to create a flexible prepared statement which can handle a variable number of input parameters.  An example query would best explain this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE
    (string_col = :param1 OR :param1 IS NULL) AND
    (double_col = :param2 OR :param2 IS NULL);
```

The idea behind this "trick" is that if a user specifies only one parameter, say `:param1`, we can just bind `null` to `:param2`, and the `WHERE` clause would then behave as if only the first parameter were even being checked.  This approach lets us handle, in theory, any number of input parameters using a single prepared statement, instead of needing to maintain many different statements.

I have gotten a simple POC working locally using pure JDBC prepared statements.  However, doing so required casting the parameter before comparing it to `NULL`, e.g.

```
WHERE (double_col = ? OR ?::numeric IS NULL)
                         ^^ does not work without cast
```

However, my actual application is using JPA, and I keep getting the following persistent error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: double precision = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The problem does *not* occur with string/text columns, but only with columns which are `double precision` in my Postgres table.  I have tried all combinations of casting, and nothing works:

```
(double_col = :param2 OR CAST(:param2 AS double precision) IS NULL);
(CAST(double_col AS double precision) = :param2 OR :param2 IS NULL);
(CAST(double_col AS double precision) = :param2 OR CAST(:param2 AS double precision) IS NULL);
```

The error seems to be saying that JDBC is sending Postgres a `bytea` type for the double columns, and then Postgres is rolling over because it can't find a way to cast `byte` to double precision.

The Java code looks something like:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlString, MyEntity.class);
query.setParameter("param1", "some value");
// bind other parameters here
List<MyEntity> = query.getResultList();
```

For reference, here are the versions of everything I am using:

```
Hibernate version         | 4.3.7.Final
Spring data JPA vesion    | 1.7.1.RELEASE
Postgres driver version   | 42.2.2
Postgres database version | 9.6.10
Java version              | 1.8.0_171
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not having received any feedback in the form of answers or even a comment, I was getting ready to give up, when I stumbled onto this excellent blog post:

[How to bind custom Hibernate parameter types to JPA queries](https://vladmihalcea.com/bind-custom-hibernate-parameter-type-jpa-query/)

The post gives two options for controlling the types which JPA passes through the driver to Postgres (or whatever the underlying database actually is).  I went with the approach using `TypedParameterValue`.  Here is what my code looks like continuing with the example given above:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlString, MyEntity.class);
query.setParameter("param1", new TypedParameterValue(StringType.INSTANCE, null));
query.setParameter("param2", new TypedParameterValue(DoubleType.INSTANCE, null));
List<MyEntity> = query.getResultList();
```

Of course, it is trivial to be passing `null` for *every* parameter in the query, but I am doing this mainly to show the syntax for the text and double columns.  In practice, we would expect at least a few of the parameters to be non `null`, but the above syntax handles all values, null or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep using plain queries with automatic parameter binding, you could try the following.

```
WHERE (? IS NULL OR (CAST(CAST(? AS TEXT) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) = double_col
```

This seems to satisfy the PostgreSQL driver's type checks as well as yielding the correct results. I haven't done much testing, but the performance hit seems minimal because the `CAST`s happen on a constant value rather than rows from the database.