# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to execute a Native Query from a Spring Boot application, but i am getting this error " org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea "

Here are the codes i have written to implement this

```
  @SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "StudentAssessmentValue",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = StudentAssessmentDTO.class,
            columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "subject_title", type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "assessment", type = String.class),
            }
    )
  )


  @NamedNativeQuery(
                    name = "getStudentSubjectsAssessment",
                    query = "SELECT\n" +
                            "   subject.subject_title,\n" +
                            "   j as assessment\n" +
                            "FROM   assessment s\n" +
                            "JOIN   LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(s.assessment) j(elem) ON (j.elem->>'student_id') = :student_id\n" +
                            "JOIN subject ON subject.id = s.subject_id\n" +
                            "WHERE s.subject_id IN (:subjects)\n" +
                            "AND s.academy_year_id = :academy_year_id\n" +
                            "AND s.term_id = :term_id\n" +
                            "AND s.section_id = :section_id"
                    ,
                    resultSetMapping = "StudentAssessmentValue"
            )
```

This is the code in my Respository

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, name = "getStudentSubjectsAssessment")
  List<StudentAssessmentDTO> getStudentAssessments2(
        @Param("student_id") String student_id,
        @Param("academy_year_id") Integer academy_year_id,
        @Param("section_id") Integer section_id,
        @Param("term_id") Integer term_id,
        @Param("subjects") Integer[] subjects
);
```

And i have this in my controller

```
   @GetMapping("/{student_id}/{academy_year_id}/{section_id}/
   term_id}")
    public List<StudentAssessmentDTO> getStudentAssessment2(
        @PathVariable("student_id") String student_id,
        @PathVariable("academy_year_id") Integer academy_year_id,
        @PathVariable("section_id") Integer section_id,
        @PathVariable("term_id") Integer term_id,
        @RequestParam(value = "subjects") Integer[] subjects
   ){
    return assessmentService.getStudentAssessments2(student_id, academy_year_id, section_id, term_id, subjects);
   }
```

I have also notice if i remove this part from the query 
             WHERE s.subject_id IN (:subjects) or say i hard code the subjects value like so s.subject_id IN (2,3,4) the code runs successfully. But if the value is coming from the request i then get the error. Here is how the request looks like

localhost:8080/assessment/f3df0bc2-7b4c-49b9-86c9-6e6b01628623/3/4/1?subjects=2,3,4

Answer (score 5):

I recently had a [similar problem to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865149/postgres-bytea-error-when-binding-null-to-prepared-statements), while also working with a native JPA query on Postgres.  Here is what worked for me:

```
// sqlString contains your native query

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlString, StudentAssessmentDTO.class);
query.setParameter("subjects", subjects);
query.setParameter("academy_year_id", new TypedParameterValue(IntegerType.INSTANCE, academy_year_id));
query.setParameter("term_id", new TypedParameterValue(IntegerType.INSTANCE, term_id));
query.setParameter("section_id", new TypedParameterValue(IntegerType.INSTANCE, section_id));
List< StudentAssessmentDTO > = query.getResultList();
```

The error you are seeing can be explained by the Postgres JDBC driver's inability to correctly pass needed type information to the database.  For instance, the following error:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea

would occur because the driver is passing the parameter to Postgres as a byte array, but the target column is integer type.  By using the above type "hints," we can force the driver to pass the correct type information.

Comment: Thanks for the response i am try to implement your solution but i am now getting this error Unknown entity: com.aprisoft.eagle_eye.dto.StudentAssessmentDTO, you should know that this is just a class like so                                                                                                                           
           public class StudentAssessmentDTO implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            private String subject_title;
           @JsonRawValue
            private String  assessment;
           }

Comment: What is the name of the entity class?  I wasn't sure of this, so I just took the DTO class.

Comment: The DTO class is to deserialize the result set i get from the query, so does entity manager deserialize a result set using a class that is not an entity?

Comment: Is that class _annotated_ with `@Entity` at the very top of the class definition?  Just do a search in your codebase for `@Entity` to see which classes you have.

Comment: This is the error i am having now org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

Comment: Use: `query.setParameter("subjects", subjects)` ... if I recall correctly, you won't need the type hint for a collection.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution to this, but it is working for me, i will be glad if anyone can still provide a better solution.

Here is what i did:

I wrote a method that will take the array gotten from the request and generate a string of this nature `"(a,b,c)"` and then added this string to my query string and it work

CODE

This is the method that build the string
**NOTE: I can afford to use this function because i know for sure them element of this array does not grow rapidly, max for my case will be 15**

```
 public String generateInSearchParameter(Integer[] inputArr){
    StringBuilder search = new StringBuilder("(");

    IntStream.range(0, inputArr.length).forEach(i -> {
        if (i != inputArr.length - 1) {
            search.append(inputArr[i]).append(',');
        } else {
            search.append(inputArr[i]);
        }
    });

     search.append(")");

     return search.toString();
  }
```

Here is the controller code

```
 @GetMapping("/{student_id}/{academy_year_id}/{section_id}/{term_id}")
    public List<StudentAssessmentDTO> getStudentAssessment2(
            @PathVariable("student_id") String student_id,
            @PathVariable("academy_year_id") Integer academy_year_id,
            @PathVariable("section_id") Integer section_id,
            @PathVariable("term_id") Integer term_id,
            @RequestParam(value = "subjects") Integer[] subjects
    ){
        return assessmentService.getStudentAssessments2(student_id, academy_year_id, section_id, term_id,generateInSearchParameter(subjects));

    }
```

Here is the code in my Service

```
public List<StudentAssessmentDTO> getStudentAssessments2(
            String student_id, Integer academy_year_id,
            Integer section_id, Integer term_id, String subjects
    ){

        String sqlString = "SELECT" +
                " subject.subject_title," +
                " j.*" +
                " FROM  assessment s" +
                " JOIN   LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(s.assessment) j(elem) ON (j.elem->>'student_id') = :student_id" +
                " JOIN subject ON subject.id = s.subject_id" +
                " WHERE s.academy_year_id = :academy_year_id" +
                " AND s.section_id = :section_id" +
                " AND s.subject_id IN " + subjects +
                " AND s.term_id = :term_id";

        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlString, "StudentAssessmentValue");
        query.setParameter("academy_year_id", new TypedParameterValue(IntegerType.INSTANCE, academy_year_id));
        query.setParameter("term_id", new TypedParameterValue(IntegerType.INSTANCE, term_id));
        query.setParameter("section_id", new TypedParameterValue(IntegerType.INSTANCE, section_id));
        query.setParameter("student_id", new TypedParameterValue(StringType.INSTANCE, student_id));

        return query.getResultList();

    }
```

I will be guard to welcome a better solution if provided